# Pre-Populate a Twitter Status with A Hashtag

Tags: twitter, urlencode

You can pre-populate a tweet by doing something like:
twitter.com/home?status=I am asking a question on stackoverflow

If you want to use a hashtag you have to urlencode it
[http://twitter.com/home?status=I am asking a question on %23stackoverflow](http://twitter.com/home?status=I%20am%20asking%20a%20question%20on%20%23stackoverflow)

If the user is not already logged into twitter, once they do log in, they are redirected to a 404 because of these hashtags. I am sure its because twitter has to save/pass through this status query string while you log in.

Any one have suggestions? A hashtag is important to me in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's rawurlencode or a similar function of your language of choice should fix that:

```
echo rawurlencode('I am asking a  question on #stackoverflow :-)');
// I%20am%20asking%20a%20%20question%20on%20%23stackoverflow%20%3A-%29
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[It was a bug in Twitter's API that has been fixed.](https://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1706)